# django simple JWT getting user ID from view level

Tags: reactjs, django

I'm making a website. For the first time I decided to make an authorization with simpleJWT. Everything works fine but I don't know how can I get logged user id or just logged user object from view.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response({'id':request.user.id})
```

request.user.id return null even if I'm logged in

this is my authorization from frontend

```
export default function Login(){
    
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(localStorage.access_token ? true : false);
    

    const submit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const user = {
            email: username,
            password: password
        };
         
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/token/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user),
        })
        
        const data = await response.json();

        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access);
        localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', data.refresh);

        setLoggedIn(true);
        
    }
    
    return(
        ...
        some form
        ...
        )
}
```

urls

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt import views as jwt_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('api/', include('posts.urls')),
    path('token/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name ='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name ='token_refresh'),
]
```

how can I get user ID from view ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `permission_classes` decorator your `test` method and let me know if works.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response({'id':request.user.id})
```

Comment: I found exact same solution as yours few minutes ago. Now I'm getting '"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."'

Comment: @KermitHQ - can you show how you are calling this API? your settings.py as well?